# variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java

I don't understand what is wrong with my code and why it produces error:

> variable k might not have been initialized

```java
import java.util.*;
public class kk
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int m=scan.nextInt();
        for(int q=0;q<m;q++)
        {
        int a=scan.nextInt();
        int b=scan.nextInt();
        int n=scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        int k;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
               k=j*b;
            }
            k=k+a;
            System.out.println(k);
            k=0;
        }}
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is quite clear; you're declaring the variable but not initializing it with a value before the loop.

Comment: What should the value of `k=k+a;` be if `k` was never given an initial value?

Comment: As the warning says. the variable `k` is not initialized. In Java, **local variables** are not initialized as default unlike **instance variables**. Local variables have to be initialized manually, e.g, `int k = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your main method/code is trying to accomplished but the variable `int k` is being considered as a local variable in your case. Please consider initializing your int primitive data type variable k with the default value of 0 before using it in the nested for-loop code block.

```
int k = 0;
```

From the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int m = scan.nextInt();
    for (int q = 0; q < m; q++) {
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        int b = scan.nextInt();
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        int k;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            k = 0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                k = j * b;
            }
            k = k + a;
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solves  "k might not have been initialized" but **changes the meaning** of the program.

Comment: That both have 'k=0;` somewhere in them doesn't make them the same,

Comment: Kevin Anderson - are you sure ?

Comment: Am I sure the order of statements in a program matters?  Uh, yeah.

Comment: Look closely at the logic of the original program, @pranav after printing on console the result of k set its value to 0 (causing it to restart), therefore to avoid "k might not have been initialized" and get the result that it is expected to initialize to "k" in that position.